# How to validate date in yyyy-mm-dd format using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to validate date in yyyy-mm-dd format using javascript. so far i have come up with this code.

```
<script>  
  function checkdate(form)  
  {  
   var a = document.forms["form"]["stdt"].value; 


    Check = /^([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})$/; 
    if(!a.match(Check)) {  
     alert("Error: Date format: ##-##-#### ");  
     return false;  
    }  

   }   
</script>
```

and HTML code

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return checkdate(this);"  method="post" action="">
```

The above will return true for 11-55-1999

Comment: So title says YYYY-MM-DD and your question says MM-DD-YYYY. So what is it?

Comment: `(1[012]|0[1-9])` will match the numbers 01..12.

Comment: Check = /^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/; 
    if(!a.match(Check)) {  
     alert("Error: Date format: ####-##-## ");  i tried this also but the result is same

Comment: Regular expression for date checking is not the best bet. leap years, does the month have 31 days, etc.

Comment: ^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$ try this regex

Comment: @BibekAryal Does not work

Comment: try and use other form of date validation than regex for the reasons pointed out by epascarello. Try using the solution provided by Rohan H @Faizan59

Answer (score 1):

I use **moment**, read the docs here http://momentjs.com/

It is simple to use, you have a value

```
var dateExample = '2016-08-23T16:09:11.690Z';
var DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY/MM/DD';    
moment(dateExample).format(DATE_FORMAT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery vaidation for that as below

```
$('#frm').validate({
      rules: {
           date_creation: {
               required: true,
               date: true
           }
      }
   });
```